# Intuitively, why do Non-monotonic Activations Work?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, activation-function

The swish/SiLU activation is very popular, and many would argue it has dethroned ReLU. However, it is non-monotonic, which seems to go against popular intuition (at least on this site: [example 1](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/25444/advantages-of-monotonic-activation-functions-over-non-monotonic-functions-in-neu), [example 2](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9233/why-do-activation-functions-have-to-be-monotonic?rq=1)).

Reading the swish paper, the justification that the authors give is that non-monotonicity "increases expressivity and improves gradient flow... [and] may also provide some robustness to different initializations and learning rates."

The authors provide an image to back up this claim, but at best this argument for non-monotonicity is vague (at worst it's a misleading way of saying "we have no clue").

Does anyone have a better justification as to why non-monotinicty is working in swish's favor?